# MySQL LEFT JOIN query is very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
SELECT bi.id, 
       bi.location, 
       bi.expense_group, 
       bi.level, 
       bi.is_active, 
       bi.type, 
       full_name, 
       Sum(DISTINCT bl.amount)                                      AS 
       BudgetAmount, 
       Sum(DISTINCT Ifnull(( bl.amount * 6 ) - ( + bal1.amount + bal2.amount + 
                                                 bal3.amount 
                                                 + bal4.amount + bal5.amount + 
                                                 bal6.amount ), 0)) AS 
       Difference, 
       Sum(DISTINCT Ifnull(Round(( + bal1.amount + bal2.amount + bal3.amount 
                                   + bal4.amount + bal5.amount + bal6.amount ) / 
                                 6), 0) 
       )                                                            AS Average, 
       Sum(DISTINCT bal1.amount)                                    AS BAL1, 
       Sum(DISTINCT bal2.amount)                                    AS BAL2, 
       Sum(DISTINCT bal3.amount)                                    AS BAL3, 
       Sum(DISTINCT bal4.amount)                                    AS BAL4, 
       Sum(DISTINCT bal5.amount)                                    AS BAL5, 
       Sum(DISTINCT bal6.amount)                                    AS BAL6 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   budget_items 
        WHERE  bi.location IS NOT NULL) AS bi 
       LEFT JOIN budget_lines AS bl 
              ON bi.id = bl.budget_item_id 
                 AND bl.budget_id = 5983 
       LEFT JOIN balance_lines AS bal1 
              ON bi.id = bal1.budget_item_id 
                 AND bal1.balance_id = 28839 
       LEFT JOIN balance_lines AS bal2 
              ON bi.id = bal2.budget_item_id 
                 AND bal2.balance_id = 28633 
       LEFT JOIN balance_lines AS bal3 
              ON bi.id = bal3.budget_item_id 
                 AND bal3.balance_id = 26664 
       LEFT JOIN balance_lines AS bal4 
              ON bi.id = bal4.budget_item_id 
                 AND bal4.balance_id = 14500 
       LEFT JOIN balance_lines AS bal5 
              ON bi.id = bal5.budget_item_id 
                 AND bal5.balance_id = 10199 
       LEFT JOIN balance_lines AS bal6 
              ON bi.id = bal6.budget_item_id 
                 AND bal6.balance_id = 7204 
GROUP  BY bi.id 
ORDER  BY bi.position
```

As you can see actually there are only 3 tables, but I need to query one of them for each of the balances.
This is taking a lot of time. Where is my mistake?

---

After struggling with @Gordon Linoff post, I tried to fix it myself. @Gordon Linoff is that what you meant?

```
     SELECT bi.id, 
       bi.location, 
       bi.expense_group, 
       bi.level, 
       bi.is_active, 
       bi.type, 
       full_name, 
       (bl.bud_amount) AS BudgetAmount, 
       (coalesce(( bl.bud_amount * 6 ) - (bal.bal_amount1 + bal.bal_amount2 + bal.bal_amount3 + bal.bal_amount4 + bal.bal_amount5 + bal.bal_amount6),
                    0)) AS Difference, 
       (coalesce(Round(( bal.bal_amount1 + bal.bal_amount2 + bal.bal_amount3 + bal.bal_amount4 + bal.bal_amount5 + bal.bal_amount6 ) / 
                                 6), 0) 
           ) AS Average, 
       bal.bal_amount1                                    AS BAL1, 
       bal.bal_amount2                                    AS BAL2, 
       bal.bal_amount3                                    AS BAL3, 
       bal.bal_amount4                                    AS BAL4, 
       bal.bal_amount5                                    AS BAL5, 
       bal.bal_amount6                                    AS BAL6 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM   budget_items bi
      WHERE  bi.location IS NOT NULL
     ) AS bi

     LEFT JOIN
     (select budget_item_id, Sum(case when budget_id = 5983 then amount end) AS bud_amount  
     from budget_lines
      group by budget_item_id
    ) AS bl
    on bl.budget_item_id = bi.id

     JOIN
     (select budget_item_id,
             IFNULL(Sum(case when balance_id = 28839 then  amount end), 0) AS bal_amount1, 
             IFNULL(Sum(case when balance_id = 28633 then  amount end), 0) AS bal_amount2, 
             IFNULL(Sum(case when balance_id = 26664 then  amount end), 0) AS bal_amount3, 
             IFNULL(Sum(case when balance_id = 14500 then  amount end), 0) AS bal_amount4,
             IFNULL(Sum(case when balance_id = 10199 then  amount end), 0) AS bal_amount5,
             IFNULL(Sum(case when balance_id = 7204 then  amount end), 0) AS bal_amount6 
      from balance_lines
      group by budget_item_id
    ) AS bal
    on bal.budget_item_id = bi.id
ORDER BY bi.location
```

Comment: What platform are you using (MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle)?

Comment: From the IfNull, it looks to me like it's MySQL

Comment: If MySQL could you post an EXPLAIN?

Comment: Hierarchical relations (6 deep!) are not going to be great for performance :( Do you have the ability to modify this schema?

Comment: PinnyM : I can't see a 6-deep hierarchy, rather 1 balance_item linked to 6 balance_lines.  Although we do have here some tricky imbrications in the big request.

Comment: @FWright. Don't know what explain is...

Comment: You can even replace those `IfNull` with `coalesce` :)

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you have `sum(distinct . . . )` you have a problem.  You are getting cartesian products on the left outer join, and your overall results will not be accurate if there are two lines that have the same amount.

I think you want to replace all those left outer join with a subquery like this:

```
select budget_item_id,
       Sum(case when budget_id = 5983 then  amount end) AS BAL, 
       Sum(case when budget_id = 28839 then  amount end) AS BAL1, 
       Sum(case when budget_id = 28633 then  amount end) AS BAL2, 
       Sum(case when budget_id = 26664 then  amount end) AS BAL3, 
       Sum(case when budget_id = 14500 then  amount end) AS BAL4,
       Sum(case when budget_id = 10199 then  amount end) AS BAL5,
       Sum(case when budget_id = 7204 then  amount end) AS BAL6 
from balance_lines
group by budget_item_id
```

and then fix the rest of the query.

Here is an attempt to write the query.  This undoubtedly has syntax errors:

```
SELECT bi.id, 
       bi.location, 
       bi.expense_group, 
       bi.level, 
       bi.is_active, 
       bi.type, 
       full_name, 
       (bl.bal) AS BudgetAmount, 
       (coalesce(( bl.bal * 6 ) - (bl.bal1 + bl.bal2 + bl.bal3 + bl.bal4 + bl.bal5 + bl.bal6),
                    0)) AS Difference, 
       (coalesce(Round(( bl.bal1 + bl.bal2 + bl.bal3 + bl.bal4 + bl.bal5 + bl.bal6 ) / 
                                 6), 0) 
           ) AS Average, 
       bl.bal1                                    AS BAL1, 
       bl.bal2                                    AS BAL2, 
       bl.bal3                                    AS BAL3, 
       bl.bal4                                    AS BAL4, 
       bl.bal5                                    AS BAL5, 
       bl.bal6                                    AS BAL6 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM   budget_items bi
      WHERE  bi.location IS NOT NULL
     ) bi left outer join
     (select budget_item_id,
             Sum(case when budget_id = 5983 then  amount end) AS BAL, 
             Sum(case when budget_id = 28839 then  amount end) AS BAL1, 
             Sum(case when budget_id = 28633 then  amount end) AS BAL2, 
             Sum(case when budget_id = 26664 then  amount end) AS BAL3, 
             Sum(case when budget_id = 14500 then  amount end) AS BAL4,
             Sum(case when budget_id = 10199 then  amount end) AS BAL5,
             Sum(case when budget_id = 7204 then  amount end) AS BAL6 
      from balance_lines
      group by budget_item_id
    ) bal
    on bal.budget_item_id = bi.id
ORDER  BY bi.position
```

Note that I entirely removed the outer `group by`, assuming that `bi.id` is a unique key on the budget items table.

Comment: It seems that you understand the problem perfectly. I do have a problem with lines that share the same amount. Can you please write the full query according to your solution? It will be of a great help, since I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Well. there are errors, and since I don't fully understand what you have done, I can't fix it  :-(. Also, the first BAL (5983) comes from a different table as you can see from my first post - budget_lines and not balance_lines. Maybe this is the source of the errors. I would be grateful if you can help!
Can you write it correctly with just 2 (bal1 and bal2), that would be enough since the query is being created dynamically.

Comment: Another question: you deleted the LEFT JOIN and used only JOIN. Will that give me all the budget items anyway? I thought that I have to use LEFT JOIN for that. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming that there is some row in `balance_line` for every budget item id, then the inner join is fine.